# cmake install library and development files as separate components using PUBLIC_HEADER

Tags: cmake

I wish to create two packages one containing a shared library and the other containing the headers for use by development.

A solution that works is:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS mylib
  COMPONENT core
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIBDIR}
)
INSTALL (
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMPONENT devel
    DESTINATION ${INCLUDEDIR}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

However CMake also has a "PUBLIC_HEADER" destination.
Such that you can do something like:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS mylib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIBDIR}
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${INCLUDEDIR}
)
```

I can't seem to get this to work. Nothing is installed to ${INCLUDEDIR} even if header files are explicitly added to ADD_LIBRARY(). Can someone point to an example of how this is supposed to work?

Another issue with this is that I want the library and the headers in different packages so ideally I want:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS mylib
  COMPONENT core
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIBDIR}
)
INSTALL(TARGETS mylib
  COMPONENT devel
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${INCLUDEDIR}
)
```

But PUBLIC_HEADER seems to require LIBRARY DESTINATION is set.
Is there a way to do this?
Are there any advantages of PUBLIC_HEADER over install DIRECTORY anyway?

Comment: I have been trying to use PUBLIC_HEADERS for this exact purpose. It's indirectly featured in Daniel Pfeiffer's talks on modern cmake and it works/installs them when run on windows. Couldn't figure out what i was doing wrong on linux...

Comment: @JonathanOlson did you get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PUBLIC_HEADER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html#prop_tgt:PUBLIC_HEADER) is almost certainly the wrong tool for the job here, unless your shared library is really an OSX framework library. The documentation also clearly points this out.

If you want header files to be copied as part of the install step, you should use the [`install(FILES ...)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/install.html#installing-files) for this:

```
install(FILES ${MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS} DESTINATION ${INCLUDEDIR} COMPONENT devel)
```

This makes sense, since CMake has no way of inferring from looking at the target which headers you might or might not want to be part of the install set. So specifying a file list manually is really the only sensible way of specifying headers for installation, and `install(FILES ...)` does exactly that.

You should avoid using glob expressions for this as well, as the potential time savings over giving the files explicitly does by no means justify the headaches they introduce when they break.

Comment: I'm not sure the documentation is as clear as that:. I (mis)read "On non-Apple platforms these headers may be installed using the PUBLIC_HEADER option to the install(TARGETS) command." as implying this was a good way of doing it. The idea of separating public and private headers somehow also appeals.

Comment: @BruceAdams I agree, that's an easy mistake to make, in particular if you are looking for a feature that does just what you asked.

Comment: CMake does have a way of inferring, public vs private headers. It even complains when you don't use $<BUILD_INTERFACE:> and $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:> for public headers despite refusing to do any installing other than on windows

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually set the `PUBLIC_HEADER` property of your library for this to work.

I put the headers into `include/mylib` so they are in their own "namespace" to avoid clashes.

Do it like this:

```
# initializes ${CMAKE_INSTALL_*DIR} to sane defaults
include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_library(
    mylib
    src/src1.cpp src/src2.cpp
    include/mylib/header1.h include/mylib/header2.h
)

# this needs to be a list, so a ; separated string in cmake
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "include/header1.h;include/header2.h")

# headers are now installed to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/mylib, and
# library into ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib or ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib64 depending on arch
install(
    TARGETS mylib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib
)
```

You can get around the bit ugly setting of the list by creating a variable like this:

```
set(MYLIB_HEADERS include/mylib/header1.h include/mylib/header2.h)
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${MYLIB_HEADERS}")
```

Docs:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GNUInstallDirs.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html

Comment: This more recent answer seems better than the one from ComicSansMS. I need to find time to test it before making it the accepted answer.

Comment: unfortunately this solution, using `PUBLIC_HEADER` won't keep the original relative folder structure of the project (if it is needed), but instead all files are flatten to the destiantion folder. This is annoying  and also means if having 2 filenames that are the same but in different subdir, it will be a problem. not sure why CMAKE is flatting the project structure when installing and forcing to install 1 file at time manually to put in the right place just to reflect the original library structure... so annoying